# Iterating thru a “Pandas Data Frame” with criteria’s from another “Pandas Data Frame”?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

*Edit: Sorry to be not clear in my question:
The Problem is, that customer B22 has three entries in the "Sales Table" but a target of only two sales, therefore I have to sum up only the first two entries and ignore the last one.*

*In the original data frame, the values in the value column are not the same.*

*I'm on pandas version 0.24.0*

I have two pandas  data frames. One with customers and sales and one with customers and sales targets. I want to sum up the sales value according to number of sales from the "Sales Target" dataframe.

Sales Table

| Index | Cust_ID | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A11 | 02.01.2021 | 100 |
| 1 | A11 | 03.01.2021 | 100 |
| 2 | A11 | 04.01.2021 | 100 |
| 3 | A11 | 05.01.2021 | 100 |
| 4 | B22 | 05.01.2021 | 100 |
| 5 | B22 | 06.01.2021 | 100 |
| 6 | B22 | 07.01.2021 | 100 |
| 7 | C33 | 08.01.2021 | 100 |
| 8 | C33 | 09.01.2021 | 100 |

Sales Targets

| Index | Cust_ID | Sales_Target |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A11 | 4 |
| 1 | B22 | 2 |
| 2 | C33 | 4 |

Customer A11 has a "Sales_Target" of 4 he bought 4 therefore a value of 400

Customer B22 has a "Sales_Target" of 2 he bought 3 therefore only a value of 200

Customer C33 has a "Sales_Target" of 3 he bought 2 therefore only a value of 200

| Index | Cust_ID | Sales_Target | Sales | Sales_Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A11 | 4 | 4 | 400 |
| 1 | B22 | 2 | 3 | 200 |
| 2 | C33 | 4 | 2 | 200 |

Sorry, I have no idea to solve the problem.

Thank you for your help.

Cheers Marcus

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want isn't a direct merge. First, transform your first table into sums grouped by customer ID:

```
sales_agg = sales.groupby('Cust_ID').agg(sales_value=('Value': 'sum'),
                                         sales_count=('Value', 'count')) \
    .reset_index()
```

Then merge your targets against this new table to introduce the new columns:

```
table3 = sales_targets.merge(sales_agg, on='Cust_ID', how='left', validate='1:1')
```

---

If you're using older Pandas, just use two groupbys:

```
sales_agg = pd.concat([
    sales.groupby('Cust_ID')['Value'].sum().rename('sales_value'),
    sales.groupby('Cust_ID')['Value'].count().rename('sales_count')],
    axis=1).reset_index()
```

Then do the merge as above.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for yout help. I tryed to use your code today and I figured out that I'm still on Pandas version 0.24. I try to change your code but I was not able to make it. It is possible that you give an advice to change your code. Thank you very much. Cheers Marcus

Comment: @Marcus see edit

Answer (score 0):

you need to marge the table and then group_by the relevant columns

in the case of the current data you can just group by customer

```
sales_df = "sales_and_customer_data"
target_df = "target_and_customer_data"

merge_df = pd.merge(sales_df,target_df,how='left',on=['Cust_ID'],copy=False)
merge_df = merge_df[['Cust_ID','Sales_Target','Value']].groupby('Cust_ID').agg(sales_value=('Value': 'sum'),sales_count=('Value', 'count'))
```

Comment: Hello, 
thank you very much for yout help. I tryed to use your code today and I figured out that I'm still on Pandas version 0.24.
I try to change your code but I was not able to make it. It is possible that you give an advice to change your code. 
Thank you very much.

Cheers Marcus